# Kernel of the homomorphism in the N/C theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H \leq G$. Define a map $\psi: N(H) \rightarrow Aut(H)$ given by $\psi(g) = \phi_g$, where $\phi_g$ is the inner automorphism of H induced by $g$: $\phi_g(h) = ghg^{-1} \forall h \in H$.

If $N(H)=\{g \in G ~s.t.~gH=Hg\}$

and $Aut(H) = \phi_g(H)=\{gHg^{-1}~\forall~g\in G\}$

I have to find the kernel of the following mapping ( homomorphism actually)

$i.e.\psi: N(H) \rightarrow Aut(H)~ ~ s.t.  ~\psi(g)=gHg^{-1}~~\forall~~g \in N(H)$

$=>\psi(g)= H gg^{-1}$ since if $g \in N(H)$, then $gH=Hg$

$=>\psi(g)= H $

Now, I want to find the kernel of the mapping $\psi$

$ker ~\psi= \{g \in G~s.t.~\psi(g)=e_{Aut ~H}\}$

**but $\psi(g)= H ~\forall~ g\in H$.**

I am confused, how do I find out the kernel of this homomoprhism?

Help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start it over and look at your first line, $\psi(g)$ is an element of $Aut(H)$, namely the conjugation by $g$, i.e. $h\mapsto ghg^{-1}\ $ (what was denoted by $\phi_g$).

What you have already verified is that this conjugation map is indeed an element $\psi(g)$ of the automorphism group of $H$, as it leaves $H$ invariant. 
However, the line $\color{red}{\psi(g)=gHg^{-1}}$ is **not correct** as it stands. What you might have had in mind is
$$(\psi(g))\big( H\big)\ =\ gHg^{-1}\ =\ H\,,$$
i.e. that the conjugation map $\psi(g):H\to H$ *is surjective*, and it indeed maps elements to $H$ into $H$.

What is the unit element $e_{Aut\ H}$? Well, that should be the identity map $id_H:H\to H$.

So, which $g\in N(H)$ will act as identity on $H$ by conjugation?

Comment: The unit element of $e_{Aut H}$ will be that inner automorphism mapping which maps $H \to H$

$i.e.~ g^{-1}Hg = H ~\forall g~\in G$

$=> Hg = gH ~\forall g~\in G$

which means $g \in C(H)$

Is my attempt right? 

Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Or in Better Detail : The unit element of $e_{Aut H}$ will be that inner automorphism mapping which maps $H \to H$. This is because firstly : $\psi(g) = H ~\forall ~g \in G$ and $\psi(g)=e_{Aut (H)} => H = e_{Aut (H)}$ and since $Aut (H)= g^{-1}Hg ~\forall ~g \in G => e_{Aut (H)}$ is some inner automorphism mapping $= g'^{-1}Hg'$

$i.e.~ g^{-1}Hg = H ~\forall g~\in G$

$=> Hg = gH ~\forall g~\in G$

which means $g \in C(H)$

Comment: No. $\psi(g)$ **does not equal to** $H$, as $\psi(g)$ is an element of the *automorphism group* of $H$, i.e. it is not a set/group (like $H$ is), but rather *an automorphism*. The elements of the automorphism group are *automorphisms*, which themselves are functions $H\to H$ (bijective and homomorphic). The unit element, what you denoted by $e_{Aut\,H}$ **is the identity function** $H\to H$, which of course coincides with the function $\psi(e)$.